# Batch script which moves ".log" files into a new folder based on date

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Batch script to move .log files of month to a new folder

```
move D:\source\log\*.log* D:\destination\log\Backup
```

Comment: 1. SO is not a free coding service, so try it yourself, and if stuck, describe your problem precisely and share your code by editing your post; 2. for your request, use search features, there are numerous similar questions here!

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample that move files older than *n* days or `dd/mm/yyyy`.

But you have to check in `forfiles /?` if the date format is regional.
In my case it's `dd/mm/yyyy`

The following batch will match every ***.log** older than `30/08/2015` so **every** `30/08/2015, 29/08/2015, 28/08/2015......01/01/1970` will be matched.

```
@echo off
set "source=D:\Interfaces\Clarity_Transaction_Interface\log"
set "destination=D:\Interfaces\Clarity_Transaction_Interface\log\Backup"

forfiles /D -30/08/2015 /p "%source%" /m *.log /C "cmd /c echo move @path \"%destination%\""
exit /B
```